# Threshold determination / prediction for cosine similarity scores

Tags: nlp, transformer, semantic-similarity

Given a query sentence, we search and find similar sentences in our corpus using transformer-based models for semantic textual similarity.

- For one query sentence, we might get 200 similar sentences with scores ranging from **0.95 to 0.55**.
- For a second query sentence, we might get 200 similar sentences with scores ranging from **0.44 to 0.27**.
- For a third query sentence, we might only get 100 similar sentences with scores ranging from **0.71 to 0.11**.

In all those cases, is there a way to predict where our threshold should be without losing too many relevant sentences? Having a similarity score of `1.0` does not mean that two documents are 2X more similar than if the score was `0.5`. Is there a way to determine the `topk` (how many of the top scoring sentences we should return) parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no satisfactory answer:

- One uses a threshold in order to avoid having to choose a specific K in a top K approach. The threshold is often selected manually to eliminate the sentences which are really not relevant. This makes this method more suitable for favouring recall, if you ask me.
- Conversely, one uses a "top K" approach in order not to select a threshold. I think K is often selected quite low in order to keep mostly relevant sentences, i.e. it's an approach more suitable for high precision tasks.

The choice depends on the task:

- First, the approach could be chosen based on what is done with the selected sentences: if it's something like question answering, one wants high precision usually. If it's information retrieval, one wants high recall. If it's a search engine, just rank the sentences by decreasing similarity.
- Then for the value itself (K or threshold), the ideal case is to do some hyper-parameter tuning. i.e. testing multiple values and evaluate the results. If this is convenient or doable for the task, then look at a few examples and manually select a value which looks reasonable.

Comment: If we assume that the task is information retrieval, but it was not domain specific, we can't really tune any hyper parameters, can we? Say, we want to find matches between a specific diabetes drug and medical articles.  This is highly specific and will yield low scores. Then we want to find matches between a general philosophical question and articles on philosophy. This is more general and may yield higher scores. I assume we want high recall on both?

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus the ideal method would be to: design an evaluation method suited to the task, e.g. have some users annotate how relevant the results are for a set of queries (btw the set of queries should be as representative as possible of the expected queries); then it would be possible to tune the threshold/K using this evaluation method. Of course this takes quite a lot of time and effort so it's not always possible.